# What function does evil mode run when I press :w?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I was wondering what function evil mode ran when I pressed `:w`. I tried using `C-h k` and then I pressed `:w` but it only registed the `:` I pressed and showed me information about `evil-ex` function instead of showing me what function is run when I save the file using `:w`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `evil-write`.

As you know, `:` call the function `evil-ex`, You can try to find related `evil-ex-*` variable which save the association list of command bindings and functions and I found it's `evil-ex-commands`.